# OpenGL Only draws for an instant

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a model in OpenGL everytime I press Q, but as soon as I let go of Q, the model dissapears. If I keep pressing Q, the model draws over and over, and I want the model to stay there

Here is the code:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(modelo.objecto.pos.x, modelo.objecto.pos.y, modelo.objecto.pos.z);
    //glRotatef(-90, 1, 0, 0);
    //glRotatef(-90, 0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005, SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005, SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005);
    mdlviewer_display(obsModel[JANELA_NAVIGATE][5]);
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

`obsModel` is a StudioModel object 
`JANELA_NAVIGATE` is the window I want to put the drawing in 
`[5]` is the model I want to draw.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: your rendering needs to occur in a constant loop

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrased your question makes it sound like you're performing the OpenGL drawing operations in the keyboard event handler itself. If that's the case, then that's your problem.

In general a event handler should only set a state variable and set a flag, that at the next iteration of the application loop performs a redraw.

Comment: Your right, and I added a flag. But still, the drawing only appears when I'm pressing the key, meaning it only draws when the flag is true. When I press the key, I see if the flag is false, if it's false, then I put it as true. In the draw method, I check to see if the flag is true, and if it is, I call the drawModel method, then I put the flag back to false.

Comment: @AdamSilva: Well, your application runs in an event loop and the usual action at the end of an event loop is to redraw the window. So when you clear the flag at the and of drawing, the next inevitable iteration of the loop with redraw without the object. Solution: Don't clear the flag in the drawing code.

Comment: Nice, it's drawing. Can you confirm me one thing? I want to draw a projectile(like a bullet) everytime I press the button. The bullet is only destroyed when it hits something. After it hits something, if I put the flag to false, the bullet will dissapear, right?

Comment: @AdamSilva: That's the general idea. Remember that OpenGL is just a drawing API. It does not retain some "scene information". It puts points, lines or triangles into pixels of a framebuffer and forgets about what it just did. So it's the programmer's part to keep all the important information around.